# Why is do i get invalid literal python3

Tags: python, python-3.8

Here is the code im trying to run:

```
numberFile = open('numbers.txt', 'r')

total = 0

for line in numberFile:
    total = total + int(line)

print("The sum of the numbers is: ", sum)

numberFile.close()
```

This is what i get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/main.py", line 11, in <module>
    total = total + int(line)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '\n'
```

I am new to python and i dont really know how to express myself in this language.

Comment: What is the value of `line` when this happens?

Comment: Note the error: `base 10: '\n'`. It's telling you what data is causing the problem (`"\n"`). You're passing a newline character to `int`.

Comment: Yeah i get it now the loop does not stop but continues to add on empty lines. Thanks guys. Its really irritating to know what to do in another language and not knowing how to express it in python.

Comment: That's just the initial friction when learning a new language. Learning the format of errors and what data iterators produce just takes practice and experience reading the documentation.

Comment: @Carcigenicate The linefeed itself is only a problem if the line is empty. `int('3\n')`, for example, returns `3` with no issue.

Comment: Yes, I suppose "You're passing a newline character to `int`" should be rephrased as "You're only passing a single newline character to `int`". The point was highlight what the important part of the error was. A lot of people seem to miss the end of that error that mentions what the bad data was.

Answer (score 1):

As the comments mentioned, just a newline, `\n`, will make the `int()` operator trip up.
To get around this, you can `strip()` each line to get rid of leading and trailing whitespace, and then just check if the line is not empty.

```py
numberFile = open('numbers.txt', 'r')

total = 0

for line in numberFile:
    line = line.strip()
    if line:
        total = total + int(line)

print("The sum of the numbers is: ", total)

numberFile.close()
```

Then, there's that sweet python one-liner that does the same thing as the loop:

```py
numberFile = open('numbers.txt', 'r')

total = sum([int(line) for line in numberFile if line.strip()])

print("The sum of the numbers is: ", total)

numberFile.close()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, i got it working. I also noticed i had forgot to print total instead of sum, my bad...